# Display data in a tabular structure as shown below

Tags: html

I am reading data from DB, iterating over it. I want to show the display it as shown below. The challenge here is it does not have side borders and there are thick lines between 2 record sets and mild lines within them. Is it possible to achieve this structure?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? You seem to be asking how to design the HTML and CSS for you, without even showing the structure of the data and without specifying the exact rendering requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's usually easier to use a table as a container with **no styling** and put a DIV in each cell and use class names on the DIVs to control the appearance.

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td>
        <div class="topRow Col1"></div>
      ... etc ...
```